# angular multiple filters with orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

i have the following statement:

```
ng-repeat="module in academy.modules | filter: {is_complete: 0}  | limitTo: 5 | orderBy:'-is_open' | pastDate: 'futureAndNull'"
```

This repeat runs over an array that looks like this:

```
  academy_id: 36
  academy_module: Object
  academy_team_id: 130
  date: null
  deadline: null
  is_complete: 0
  is_open: 0
  module: Object
  module_id: 38
  prevName: "Konstruktionstest"
  score_to_pass: 40
  sort_number: 11
  user_id: 114
```

Some of the arrays has the value `is_open` set to `1`

The elements with combination: `is_open = 1` & `is_complete = 0` is the ones i want to show as the first item(s)

if you look at the first filter i first filter the ones where `is_complete = 0` and then in the `orderBy` i filter by `is_open` (DESC)

However this does not work.

The reason i am not filtering on `is_open = 1` is because i want to show the other elements aswell and these would not be visible then.

So what can i do?